# Scala - looping over case class names to use as type parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a function like this in Scala code (Scala 2.13) for use with Spark

```scala
def getDataset[T <: Product: TypeTag](name:String): Dataset[T] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val ds = spark.read.parquet(BASE_PATH + "/" + name).as[T]
    ds.createOrReplaceTempView(name)
    ds
}
```

Now I want to turn a `Seq` of case classes, and for each class, call this function:

```
case class CLASS1(...)
case class CLASS2(...)
case class CLASS3(...)

Seq(CLASS1, CLASS2, CLASS3, ....).foreach {
  c => getDataset[c??](name=c???)
}
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the exact syntax; the symbol for the name of the case class, represented by the variable `c` inside the `foreach`, seems to represent the type of the `apply` method (`() => Product`). What I really want is the *type* of the case class to use as the type parameter, and the *name* of the case class.

It feels like I should be able to do this - what am I missing here?

**Update** It looks like it's possible to get the name of the type used in a type parameter at runtime, via `TypeTag`.

The solution I am converging on is something like this:

```
def getDataset[T <: Product: TypeTag]: Dataset[T] = {
    import spark.implicits._

    val name = typeTag[T].tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString
    val ds = spark.read.parquet(BASE_PATH + "/" + name).as[T]
    ds.createOrReplaceTempView(name)
    ds
}
```

Then something like `Seq(getDataset[CLASS1], getDataset[CLASS2], ...)`

Not what I hoped for, but at least I can cut out the copy-paste of the class name and string.

Comment: How are you even constructing this `Seq` in Scala 2?  All collections in Scala 2 are homogeneous. You can't have a sequence of elements where each element is an instance of a different class

Comment: Is this a `Seq[Class[_]]` maybe?

Comment: Ah ok, so they are all of the same type, it's that the seq might be a `Seq[A]` for any `A`. writing `class1, class2, class3` was a little bit confusing. Does `c.getClass` not suffice here for some reason ?

Comment: No, it's the case class names, but apparently the symbol for the case class name is being interpreted as the apply function rather than as the class, so it's a homogenous `Seq[() => Product]`

Comment: @wrschneider In `Seq(Class1, Class2, Class3)` `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3` are the companion objects of case classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you want to substitute `T` (known at compile time) at type level and `name` (known at runtime) at value level.

Normally `T` and `name` do not exist at the same time.

One option is to replace `Seq(Class1, Class2, Class3)` on value level with `Class1 :: Class2 :: Class3 :: HNil` on type level and use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

```
import shapeless.{::, HNil, Poly0, Poly1, Typeable}
import shapeless.ops.hlist.FillWith
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

object datasetPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[T <: Product : TypeTag /*: Typeable*/]: Case.Aux[T, Dataset[T]] = 
    at(_ => getDataset[T](/*Typeable[T].describe*/typeOf[T].toString))
}

object nullPoly extends Poly0 {
  implicit def cse[T >: Null]: Case0[T] = at(null)
}

FillWith[nullPoly.type, Class1 :: Class2 :: Class3 :: HNil].apply().map(datasetPoly)
```

Alternatively you can use [macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) or [runtime reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html).
In `Seq(Class1, Class2, Class3)` `Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3` are the companion objects of case classes.
For example with [reflective toolbox](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-parse-on-toolboxes)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Quasiquote
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm}
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

val tb = cm.mkToolBox()

Seq(Class1, Class2, Class3).foreach(c => {
  val classSymbol = cm.reflect(c).symbol.companion
  tb.eval(q"App.getDataset[$classSymbol](${classSymbol.name.toString})")
})
```

You should add to `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer since I think the hard problem here is simply, that you can't specify type parameters at runtime without reflection and I need to find another option.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own companion objects for the case classes and include a method in each which calls `getDataset`.  For example, this should work (passed by my mental compiler):

```scala
abstract class DatasetProvider[T <: Product : TypeTag] {
  val name: String
  def dataset: Dataset[T] =
    getDataset[T](name)
}

case class Class1(...)

object Class1 extends DatasetProvider[Class1] {
  override val name: String = "class1"
}

// and so forth for Class2, Class3

Seq(Class1, Class2, Class3).foreach { c =>
  val ds = c.dataset
  ???
}
```

Note that if defining your own companion object, you will have to explicitly mark it as a function if you want to use it as one: this may or may not be desirable.

Comment: I replaced `trait DatasetProvider[T]` with `abstract class DatasetProvider[T <: Product : TypeTag]` in order to satisfy `getDataset` bounds.

Comment: Any resemblance between my mental compiler and the actual compirler is coincidental :)